# Исходный код сайта приравнять к переменной

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа. Допустим, заходим на какой-н будь сайт/страницу (скажем "X"), смотрим исходный код.

1. Можно ли определить количество строк в сайте/странице "X"?
2. Можно ли определить значение всей строки (допустим 5-й)?
3. Найденное в п1 и п2 приравнять к переменным на PHP.

Comment: парси HTML

Comment: если я неправильно спросил, сори. что то не понятно? мне охота имея свой сайт вносить туда адрес определенной страницы. сайт должен уметь обратится к этой странице и сделать указанной выше. такой возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*1*/ $a = file('http://site.ru');
      $al = sizeof($a);
/*2*/ echo $a[4];
/*3*/ $al, $a[4];
```

Так сойдет? =)

Comment: вполне. сейчас буду пробовать 8-)